# Convert data from a Cookie into a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

So I'm storing jQuery button clicks in cookies. i.e, each time a user clicks a button I update the count for that cookie. This is with an aim of sorting them in ascending order.

At the moment I'm stuck trying to get assign the Cookie data to a string - I want the values to be in the background so I can sort them, but I need to show text in the html.

Code example of what I am trying to do ( I have 5 of these functions):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var Cookie = $.cookie('worldCookie');

  if(Cookie==null || Cookie=='')
  {
    //set values to 0
    $.cookie('worldCookie', 0);
}

  $("#worldTab").click(function() {
    var Cookie = $.cookie('worldCookie');
    Cookie = parseInt(Cookie) + 1;
    // increment cookie to 1
    $.cookie('worldCookie', Cookie);

    $('.worldText').text(Cookie).show();

  });
});
```

And then I have 5 of these (Which i want to sort eventually):

```
  <div class="worldText">World News</div>
```

Comment: so, what's the trouble.first，the five node has the same class name?

Comment: Please define a specific problem

Comment: All the cookies have different names. All the divs have different classes. I want to assign a cookie to a Div. And then sort them in ascending order.